# How to submit Firefox 4 feedback without using Feedback extension?

Tags: firefox

Mozilla Firefox 4 "Feedback" provides a simple and convenient (no need to register in Mozilla bug tracker, for example) way to report Firefox 4 bugs. But it annoys me by placing a huge irremovable "feedback" button right in main toolbar, so I've disabled it. Is there an alternative way (a simple web form for example) to submit feedback with the same ease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can post a message (email) to all the list members of feedback, but an app is needed to open the link/ Gmail, Windows Live or Yahoo! Mail. It's okay if you use one of them. I have Windows Live on my desktop. I clicked on link, then selected Windows Live, then ok. It opens with the address in place ready to mail.

[Feedback details](https://lists.mozilla.org/listinfo/feedback-firefox)

The link on page is feedback - firefox@lists.mozilla.org. [The mozilla.org mail list](https://lists.mozilla.org/listinfo) - they all need the app to open.

Comment: @Ivan, sorry if you saw 'no you can not before' i clicked on my win live and nothing happened, so i figured you had to add an app to firefox,passed by later and re-checked and it opened.re-edited.again sorry if wasted your time